# Jmeter - retrieve embedded resources for url with username:pwd

Tags: jmeter

I have my Web Server/IP as

```
      http://username:password@site/path
```

in my HTTP Request Page in JMeter. I have checked "Retrieve Embedded Resources" in the page. The resources that are retrieved just show up as

```
       http://site/path
```

and hence fails with a 404 Authentication error. How should i set up for the embedded resources also to include the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove username and password from your URL
2. Add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) to your Test Plan and provide username and password there

HTTP Authorization Manager will automatically add basic authentication header to all requests including embedded and it should resolve the issue.